# Can I transfer tokens between HD wallet children without any gas fees?

Tags: wallets

I am creating a centralized wallet service. I want to hold the transaction history on my centralized database and don't want to pay any fees between my user's transfers. Can I do this between HD wallet children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think addresses in HD wallets have a parent-child relation. Each wallet address is derived from the a common private key or a different private key. So in effect they are standalone addresses and that means transfers between addresses from the same HD wallet need gas.

Comment: I think you are right, i need to find another solution for this problem like some data place for transactions in the wallet to identify every user.

Answer (score 0):

Addresses in HD wallets don't have any connection as far as the blockchain is concerned, so you have to transfer using the normal method. They are all separate addresses, so I don't think your idea will work. If you are open to using L2s, they normally have *much* lower fees. For example, a simple transaction on Polygon will cost about 0.003 MATIC, or about 0.3¢.